# Highlight specific days on date picker

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is it possible to highlight specific days on flutter showDatePicker standard widget?

I need to highlight specific days in which I already have set appointments, something like this:

[image]

On 16-17 and 30 Sep 2020 I've already set appointments and I need to show them when user open the calendar.

This is my actual basic implementation

```dart
final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: _selectedDate,
      firstDate: DateTime(2015, 8),
      lastDate: DateTime(2101),
      selectableDayPredicate: (date) {
        // If not Sunday or Saturday return day as clicable
        if (date.weekday != 6 && date.weekday != 7) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      },
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

you can not show specific days in the `showDatePicker` widget as far as I know.
that's why there is package for that to show the marker of particular date.
i have one example which I can share with you

```
  // More advanced TableCalendar configuration (using Builders & Styles)
  Widget _buildTableCalendarWithBuilders() {
    return TableCalendar(
      locale: 'pl_PL',
      calendarController: _calendarController,
      events: _events,
      holidays: _holidays,
      initialCalendarFormat: CalendarFormat.month,
      formatAnimation: FormatAnimation.slide,
      startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.sunday,
      availableGestures: AvailableGestures.all,
      availableCalendarFormats: const {
        CalendarFormat.month: '',
        CalendarFormat.week: '',
      },
      calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
        outsideDaysVisible: false,
        weekendStyle: TextStyle().copyWith(color: Colors.blue[800]),
        holidayStyle: TextStyle().copyWith(color: Colors.blue[800]),
      ),
      daysOfWeekStyle: DaysOfWeekStyle(
        weekendStyle: TextStyle().copyWith(color: Colors.blue[600]),
      ),
      headerStyle: HeaderStyle(
        centerHeaderTitle: true,
        formatButtonVisible: false,
      ),
      builders: CalendarBuilders(
        selectedDayBuilder: (context, date, _) {
          return FadeTransition(
            opacity: Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(_animationController),
            child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0, left: 6.0),
              color: Colors.deepOrange[300],
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              child: Text(
                '${date.day}',
                style: TextStyle().copyWith(fontSize: 16.0),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
        todayDayBuilder: (context, date, _) {
          return Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0, left: 6.0),
            color: Colors.amber[400],
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            child: Text(
              '${date.day}',
              style: TextStyle().copyWith(fontSize: 16.0),
            ),
          );
        },
        markersBuilder: (context, date, events, holidays) {
          final children = <Widget>[];

          if (events.isNotEmpty) {
            children.add(
              Positioned(
                right: 1,
                bottom: 1,
                child: _buildEventsMarker(date, events),
              ),
            );
          }

          if (holidays.isNotEmpty) {
            children.add(
              Positioned(
                right: -2,
                top: -2,
                child: _buildHolidaysMarker(),
              ),
            );
          }

          return children;
        },
      ),
      onDaySelected: (date, events) {
        _onDaySelected(date, events);
        _animationController.forward(from: 0.0);
      },
      onVisibleDaysChanged: _onVisibleDaysChanged,
      onCalendarCreated: _onCalendarCreated,
    );
  }
```

for more information you can go to this package
https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar